# Kafka Persistence State-Store Not Worked with combined use of python and java

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Today i found very strange thing in Kafka state store i google lot but didn't found the reason for the behavior.

Consider the below state store written in **java**:

```
private KeyValueStore<String, GenericRecord> userIdToUserRecord;
```

There are **two** processor who are using this state store.

```
  topology.addStateStore(userIdToUserRecord, ALERT_PROCESSOR_NAME, USER_SETTING_PROCESSOR_NAME)
```

**USER_SETTING_PROCESSOR_NAME** will put the data to state store

```
userIdToUserRecord.put("user-12345", record);
```

**ALERT_PROCESSOR_NAME** will get the data from state store

```
userIdToUserRecord.get("user-12345");
```

**Adding source to UserSettingProcessor**

```
userSettingTopicName = user-setting-topic;    
topology.addSource(sourceName, userSettingTopicName)
                    .addProcessor(processorName, UserSettingProcessor::new, sourceName);
```

**Adding source to AlertEngineProcessor**

```
alertTopicName = alert-topic;
topology.addSource(sourceName, alertTopicName)
                    .addProcessor(processorName, AlertEngineProcessor::new, sourceName);
```

**Case 1:**
Produce record using Kafka produce in java
First produce record to topic **user-setting-topic** using java it will add the user record to state store
Second produce record to topic **alert-topic** using java it will take record from state store using user id *userIdToUserRecord.get("user-12345");*

Worked fine i am using kafkaavroproducer to produce record to both the topic

**Case 2:**
First produce record to topic **user-setting-topic** using **python** it will add the user record to state store *userIdToUserRecord.put("user-100", GenericRecord);

Second produce record to topic **alert-topic** using java it will take record from state store using user id *userIdToUserRecord.get("user-100");*

the strange happen here userIdToUserRecord.get("user-100") will return null

I check the scenario like this also
i produce record to user-setting-topic using python then the userSettingProcessor process method triggered there is check in debug mode and try to get user record from state store userIdToUserRecord.get("user-100") it worked fine in userSettingProcessor i am able to get the data from state-store

Then i produce record to alert-topic using java then try to get the userIdToUserRecord.get("user-100") it will return null

i don't know this strange behavior anyone tell me about this behavior.

**Python code:**

```
value_schema = avro.load('user-setting.avsc')
value = {
    "user-id":"user-12345",
    "client_id":"5cfdd3db-b25a-4e21-a67d-462697096e20",
    "alert_type":"WORK_ORDER_VOLUME"
}

print("------------------------Kafka Producer------------------------------")
avroProducer = AvroProducer(
    {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'schema.registry.url': 'http://localhost:8089'},
    default_value_schema=value_schema)
avroProducer.produce(topic="user-setting-topic", value=value)
print("------------------------Sucess Producer------------------------------")
avroProducer.flush()
```

Java Code:

```
 Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);

        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("alert_id","5cfdd3db-b25a-4e21-a67d-462697096e20");
        record.put("alert_created_at",123449437L);
        record.put("alert_type","WORK_ORDER_VOLUME");
        record.put("client_id","5cfdd3db-b25a-4e21-a67d-462697096e20");
        //record.put("property_key","property_key-"+i);

        record.put("alert_data","{\"alert_trigger_info\":{\"jll_value\":1.4,\"jll_category\":\"internal\",\"name\":\"trade_Value\",\"current_value\":40,\"calculated_value\":40.1},\"work_order\":{\"locations\":{\"country_name\":\"value\",\"state_province\":\"value\",\"city\":\"value\"},\"property\":{\"name\":\"property name\"}}}");
        return record;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Java producer and the Python producer (that is based on the C producer) use a different default hash-function for data partitioning. You will need to provide a customized partitioning to one (or both) to make sure they use the same partitioning strategy.

Unfortunately, the Kafka protocol dose not specify what the default partitioning hash function should be and thus clients can use whatever they want by default.